# Can strong adjectives have comparative and superlative?

Tags: adjectives, superlatives, comparative, intensifiers

I learnt that strong adjectives are "ungradable" so for example the adjective *enormous* can't be used with intensifiers such as *very, slightly, a little, a bit, extremely, terribly, etc*. So I wonder if this kind of adjectives can have comparative and superlative?

Comment: Please give examples of what you're wondering about.

Comment: That elephant is rather enormous, wouldn't you say?  It is more enormous than any I've ever seen. It's possibly the most enormous elephant on the planet.

Comment: Beware of "authoritative" lists of ungradable adjectives. In practice, there is no hard and fast rule governing the use of a comparative or intensifier with such adjectives. One of the most thoughtful treatments of the subject I've found is **[here.](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2012/02/gradable-and-ungradable-adjectives.html)**